# groupby produces a different mean when done at two levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset (`df`) about the `Time` spent by different users (`UserId`). Users can belong to different `Group`s (1, 2, 3).

```
  UserId  Time  Group
0 181915  52    3 
1 128004  52    2 
2 178974  40    1 
3 182887  30    1
4 238434  50    2
```

I am trying to compute the average `Time` spent by each user `Group`. I know that this is a easy task.

```
df.groupby('Group')['Time'].mean()
```

The code above works just fine. However, I have the following alternative  where I group the data by both 'Group' and 'UserId' and then compute the mean per user within each group, and then take the mean of the computed means for the whole group. Below is an example for Group 1:

```
df.groupby(['Group', 'UserId')['Time'].mean().loc[1].mean()
```

However, this produces a different result. I do not understand why it works this way. At the end, I take average of everything. I do not which result should I trust. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I think [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133138/will-the-mean-of-a-set-of-means-always-be-the-same-as-the-mean-obtained-from-the) answers your question

Comment: @sudden_appearance thanks! I am not sure when to use mean of means.

Comment: you need to give us a desired output, it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish